# Is it explosive dog or explosives dog?

Tags: morphology

I can't seem to find a justification either way for this example. Can anyone help me out? Thank you!

In the context of a bomb-sniffing dog, what grammar rule would justify using the (s)? Is it simply a matter of avoiding confusion? thanks!

Comment: An "_explosive_ dog" is one that has a tendency to explode.

Comment: Out of context, it pretty much has to be _explosives dog_, meaning a dog that sniffs out explosives (best guess). _Explosive dog_ would mean a dog that might explode.

Comment: both have appeared in the relationship between man and dog.

Comment: Hello, AMG. As you will see argued on other similar threads, it is usual (though not mandatory) to use the singular form of a noun when using it attributively. Here there is an obvious complication: there is an intercategorial polyseme – the word 'explosive' already exists, is in common use, and has a well-known meaning. // And this has little to do with grammar.

Comment: An "explosive dog" is one that has a propensity to fart.

Answer (score 5):

Even though you usually use the singular form of a noun as a modifier before another noun ("night clothes", even though they're for many nights), there are exceptions, of which this is one: you say "explosives dog" and never "explosive dog" to refer to a dog that detects explosives. I guess this is because "explosive dog" means a dog liable to explode.